# Counting empty textareas with Jquery

Tags: jquery, filter, textarea

I have 5 text areas on my form and I want to count all empty textareas.  One textarea is populated by a database.

When i use the following code and log out the console I get 3.333333333333332. I expect to get 4

Every time i make a change to one of the textareas, the value goes up or down.

This works fine in input boxes but not textareas

What could be causing the problem?

```
var test = $('textarea').filter(function() {
                return !$(this).text();
           }).length;
```

Comment: I don't know how you can possibly get a floating point number for this code. It seems to work fine here: http://jsfiddle.net/fsyxvned/

Comment: Both Chrome and Firefox come up with a floating point number but if i log out `console.log($('textarea').length);`, I get 5

Comment: Can you create a fiddle?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to use:

```
!$.trim( $(this).val() );
```

Instead of:

```
!$(this).text();
```

Comment: Although your approach is better, it does not explain why the questioner ends up with a floating-point value in `length`.